# How would you return an Observable<T> from a function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have this function:

```
  getData(): Observable<ServerResponse> {
    const data = {} as ServerResponse;

    data.client = this.getClientData().pipe(
      map(response =>
        response.map(x => {
          return x.data.client;
        }),
      ),
    );

    data.otherData = this.otherData().pipe(
      map(response =>
        response.map(x => {
          return this.groupByTimePeriod(x.data.other, 'day', 'week');
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The function need to return `data` with all the properties that gets assigned to that inside a function. How would you do that?

If I just do return `data` it is does not work as `this.getClientData()` and `this.otherData()` has not yet being completed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, you have multiple questions/problems here. I'll start with the easiest. How do you get an observable from a function/object? The answer is via observable [of](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of):

```js
return of(data);
```

But you eluded to a larger problem, which is: how do you defer returning data until child observables emit their values? You are looking for [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin). Via the docs:

> `forkJoin` will wait for all passed Observables to complete and then it will emit an array with last values from corresponding Observables. So if you pass `n` Observables to the operator, resulting array will have `n` values, where first value is the last thing emitted by the first Observable, second value is the last thing emitted by the second Observable and so on. That means `forkJoin` will not emit more than once and it will complete after that.

You also have several other problems. For example, you are never subscribing to `this.getClientData()` or `this.otherData()`. Observables are lazily executed. Code in your observable will not execute until something subscribes to it. From [the docs](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable#executing-observables):

> The code inside `Observable.create(function subscribe(observer) {...})` represents an "Observable execution", *a lazy computation that only happens for each Observer that subscribes*.

It also appears as though you are using `pipe/map` in an attempt to set a property on your `data` object. But you're never setting `data.client` or `data.other`, so they will always be empty.

So, putting it all together, here's what your code might look like, with simulated server latency to show that `forkJoin` waits for completion of both observables:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {
    getData(): Observable<ServerResponse> {
        const allOperations = forkJoin(
            this.getClientData(),
            this.getOtherData()
        );

        const observable = Observable.create(function subscribe(observer) {
            // Wait until all operations have completed
            allOperations.subscribe(([clientData, otherData]) => {
                const data = new ServerResponse;
                // Update your ServerReponse with client and other data
                data.otherdata = otherData.other;
                data.client = clientData.client;
                // Now that data is 100% populated, emit to anything subscribed to getData().
                observer.next(data);
                observer.complete();
            });

        });
        // We return the observable, with the code above to be executed only once it is subscribed to
        return observable;
    }

    getClientData() : Observable<any> {
        return of({ client: 'Client 1' });
    }
    getOtherData(): Observable<any> {
        // Fake server latency
        return of({ other: 'Other data that takes a while to return from server...' })
            .pipe(delay(2000));
    }
}

export class ServerResponse {
    client: string;
    otherdata: string;
}
```

If you call `getData()` **and subscribe to the observable**, you will see that `forkJoin` works as intended and we have to wait 2 seconds for both child observables to complete and our observable to emit a value:

```js
this.testService.getData().subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

It seems that you might be new to RxJS / asynchronous programming. I suggest reading [the excellent introduction](https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview) to RxJs when you get a chance. It can be tricky at first but with practice this will come to be second nature.

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution with a such detailed explanation. I will try it out and see if it is works.

Comment: Excellent! But the syntax has changed, so to create the observable (in Typescript anyway) it's now:
`const observable:Observable<MyClass> = new Observable((observer:Observer<MyClass>) => { ...`